# Why does my list stop showing horizontally when I add a div?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a horizontal list.  Here is my `html`:

```
<ul class="deals">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>fads</li>
    <li>asdf</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the `css`:

```
ul.deals {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.deals li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

If I add a `div` inside of the list, then it does not show horizontally anymore.  Here is the new `html`:

```
<ul class="deals">
    <li>
        <div>test</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>fads</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>asdf</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What about the `div` changes the output?  Also, how would I fix this?

Comment: Because divs are block element, you need some CSS to turn them into `display: inline` too. Or use inline tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, divs are block level elements.

What are you trying to achieve by nesting a div?  If you don't need a dimensional container just use a `<span>` rather than using a `<div>` styled with `display: inline`. Reason: spans are inline by nature and won't need additional css to make them so.

If you want a dimensional container while still retaining your horizontal structure you can use either a `<span>` or `<div>` as long as you assign `display: inline-block`

Even better, style the list item itself with `display: inline-block`.  That way you don't need the nested DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

As gillesc said, DIV tags are block level. Try the following dubious code in your css

```
ul.deals div {display: inline}
```

You could possibly use inline-block instead